# Can I use <see cref> outside of method declaration

Tags: c#, comments, documentation

I need to use a `///<see cref="">` in a comment that is inside a function, and I can only make it work when in the  of the method declaration.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? If so, how?

So essentially I need this :

```
///<summary>
///this is a summary where i can use the <see cref=""> with ease
///</summary>
internal virtual void OnClick()
{
    if (player.IsPlaying || player.IsBuffering)
    {
        //Some lengthly comment about code that I erased for simplicity
        //And I would like to add a <see cref=""> somewhere around here.
        player.Stop(false);
    }

        item.TogglePlayStop();
    }
}
```

If I place it inside the method, I get `XML Comment is not placed on a valid language element`. Outside works fine.

I'd like to do this because what I'm explaining in the comment is irrelevant to the method, only relevant to a small portion of the code. I'm working on legacy code and had to add something smelly. I don't want people to remove it by mistake, and I certainly don't want people to waste time on it. It's simple once you see the whole picture, and to that I just wanted to add a link, so people don't have to copy paste the class name to navigate, they can just click in my comment (which is 7 lines long)

Comment: Yes, theoretically you can; but you'd have to use `///` as comment. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I tried to use triple slashes but I didn't work ; I'm not sure why. Did you try yourself (to confirm I'm doing something wrong) ?

I added an explanation in the question

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really tired ; I know why it didnt' work. The error is quite self explanatory : cant' place XML comment on invalid language elements. I'm assuming it's trying to document "inside the method" but can't because it's too deep to be valid for the system?

Comment: XML comments are inputs for a help compiler, so you should consider how such a system would handle this. Documentation is always in reference to *some code element*, such as a namespace, class, method, or property. Documenting a single branch of an `if` statement doesn't fit neatly into the paradigm. I would put your comment into the method's documentation as `<remarks>`.

Comment: Yeah, it will tell you that the language element is invalid; but it's only a warning and won't throw an error. The link to the class should work (though the highlighting of the names not), I have just tested it again.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann Indeed, it's only a warning and it works in Visual Studio. I was working using IntelliJ Rider and that IDE did not behave as expected. My bad, should've tried with another IDE first !
Thank you for your time :)